# Remove version number (continuous integers and dots) from a string list

Tags: python

I have a string list contains program name and version numbers, for example:
['Adobe PDF Library 9.9', 'Adobe PDF Library 8.0', 'Adobe PDF Library 15.0', 'Adobe PDF Library 11.0', 'Mac OS X 10.13.3 Quartz PDFContext'].

I am doing statistical analysis and need to remove all the version numbers and only retain the program name. The version number may have multiple sections and dots, and may appear any any part of the string.

Is there an efficient way to achieve the goal using regex to match the pattern, but without using a regular for-loop to exam each item manually?

Comment: Can you share what you’ve tried so far as a [mre] per [ask]?

Comment: The only way I can think of is to use a for loop to examine each item in the list, and the remove the digits and dots if they have it, which I think is awkward. I have no clue how can I do it more efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with a regex that matches a space followed by digits followed by zero or more `.` and digits:

```
import re

l = [
    'Adobe PDF Library 9.9', 
    'Adobe PDF Library 8.0', 
    'Adobe PDF Library 15.0', 
    'Adobe PDF Library 11.0', 
    'Mac OS X 10.13.3 Quartz PDFContext',
    'Notes',
    '100Things 10.2',
    'Photoshop 1'
]

rx = re.compile('\s\d+(\.\d+)*')

[rx.sub('', s) for s in l]
```

Which produces:

```
['Adobe PDF Library',
 'Adobe PDF Library',
 'Adobe PDF Library',
 'Adobe PDF Library',
 'Mac OS X Quartz PDFContext',
 'Notes',
 '100Things',
 'Photoshop']
```

Comment: Exactly what I expected, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to match the version number, and filter it out if there's a match. The expression matches one or more instances of a number concatenated with a period, followed by a number:

```py
[' '.join(token for token in item.split(' ') if not re.match("(\d+\.)+\d+$", token)) for item in data]
```

This outputs:

```py
['Adobe PDF Library', 'Adobe PDF Library', 'Adobe PDF Library', 'Adobe PDF Library']
```

Comment: @dovod74538 -- Updated. Let me know your thoughts.